# amsart/amsbook with non-default glossary style

Tags: glossaries, amsbook

I am using `amsbook` with the `glossaries` package. The following MWE produces a glossary in which the single entry is completely squashed up in the middle; it looks like no space at all has been allocated for the second column. Is there some conflict between `amsbook` (and `amsart`) and the non-default glossary styles?

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\glossarystyle{long3col}
\newglossaryentry{x}{name=x,description={a helpful description of x}}
\begin{document}
Here is \gls{x}.
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

The glossary is fine if either I switch to a non-AMS document class, or I switch to the default glossary style, neither of which I want to do.

The only similar problem I can find is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53173/undefined-control-sequence-glossarytoctitle-using-amsbook, but I haven't changed the font size or linespread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `long3col` style uses a `longtable` environment whose second column is a `p` column with the width of the length `\glsdescwidth` and whose third column is of the same type with the width of `\glspagelistwidth`. These lengths, in turn, are defined as `0.6\hsize` resp. `0.1\hsize`, and `amsbook` (for whatever reason) sets `\hsize` to zero. Redefining `\glsdescwidth` to `0.6\textwidth` and `\glspagelistwidth` to `0.1\textwidth` seems to fix your problem.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\glossarystyle{long3col}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.6\textwidth}
\setlength{\glspagelistwidth}{0.1\textwidth}
\newglossaryentry{x}{name=x,description={a helpful description of x}}
\begin{document}
Here is \gls{x}.
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image]