# amsbook with multiple page glossary

Tags: glossaries, amsbook

I'm not sure if the protocol is to edit my previous post [amsart/amsbook with non-default glossary style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66544/amsart-amsbook-with-non-default-glossary-style) to add this question, but it is certainly related.

There seems to be another conflict between the AMS document classes and the glossary package, which occurs when the glossary runs to more than one page. The error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \glossarytoctitle
```

Here's the MWE. (I say `minimal': there might be a few more lines than needed, but it's minimal in complexity.)

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{q}{name=q,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{w}{name=w,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{e}{name=e,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{r}{name=r,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{t}{name=t,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{y}{name=y,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{u}{name=u,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{i}{name=i,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{o}{name=o,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{p}{name=p,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{l}{name=l,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{k}{name=k,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{j}{name=j,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{h}{name=h,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{g}{name=g,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{f}{name=f,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{d}{name=d,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{s}{name=s,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{a}{name=a,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{z}{name=z,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{x}{name=x,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{c}{name=c,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{v}{name=v,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{b}{name=b,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{n}{name=n,description=blah}
\newglossaryentry{m}{name=m,description=blah}

\begin{document}

\gls{q}
\gls{w}
\gls{e}
\gls{r}
\gls{t}
\gls{y}
\gls{u}
\gls{i}
\gls{o}
\gls{p}
\gls{l}
\gls{k}
\gls{j}
\gls{h}
\gls{g}
\gls{f}
\gls{d}
\gls{s}
\gls{a}
\gls{z}
\gls{x}
\gls{c}
\gls{v}
\gls{b}
\gls{n}
\gls{m}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: IMO, it was correct to ask a new question, as the two issues, though both being conflicts between `amsbook` and `glossaries`, are not related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really know why the error is raised; you can correct it by saying

```
\providecommand{\glossarytoctitle}{\glossaryname}
```

after loading `glossaries`.